# What is the Fourier series of $f(x) = \begin{cases} -2, & -4<x<-2 \\ x, & {-2<x<2} \\ 2, & {2<x<4} \end{cases}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition, fourier-series

What is the Fourier series of $f(x) = \begin{cases}  -2, & -4<x<-2 \\  x, & {-2<x<2} \\  2, & {2<x<4}  \end{cases}$

I have already established that this function is an odd function and has a period of 8, however, I do not know how to move forward with this. Any explanation on what definition of $f(x)$ should I follow would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This period value was given to me by my lecturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

If the function $f$ is odd on the symmetric interval $[-L,L]$, then you have the Fourier sine series

$$
f(x)\sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin (\frac{n\pi x}{L})
$$
where the coefficients are given by
$$
a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x)\sin (\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx
$$

---

Notes.

In your example,

$$
\int_0^4 f(x)\sin (\frac{n\pi x}{4})dx
=\int_0^2x\sin (\frac{n\pi x}{4})dx
+\int_2^42\sin (\frac{n\pi x}{4})dx
$$

Comment: My main problem here isn't with the process of obtaining the series itself - it's with which function I need to substitute $f(x)$ with. P.S Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @gann: you are welcome. See edits.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why aren't there 3 integrals? (one for each case)

Comment: @gann: looking at the abstract setting in the hint, you only integrate on the interval $[0,L]$, where there are only two cases for your function $f$.